# Java. Число сочетаний из N по М

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть задача: Нужно реализовать функцию, которая будет искать число сочетаний из N по M, только с определенными условиями:
Функция должна возвращать получающийся результат, если он не превышает 10^9. В противном случае функция должна вернуть -1.

Для вычисления результата внутри функции нужно выполнять последовательное умножение и деление результата на соответствующие значения. Например, число сочетаний из 7 по 3, то есть величину 7! / (3! * 4!), можно посчитать так. Сначала сократим 7! и 4!, получим выражение (5 * 6 * 7) / (1 * 2 * 3). Это выражение можно посчитать, домножив результат, который проинициализирован единицей на 7 и поделив на 1, затем домножив его на 6 и поделив на 2, затем домножив его на 5 и поделив на 3.

Ошибка в том, что неправильно реализовано сравнение с 10^9

```
public static long Combine(int n,int m) {
    if (n==0&&m==0) return 1;
    else if (m==0) return 1;
    else if (n==m) return 1;
    int bol=0;
    int men=0;
    if (m>=n/2+1) {
        bol = m;
        men=n-m;
    }
    else {
        bol=n-m;
        men=m;           //Находим значения, которые будут снизу дроби
    }

    int[] t = new int[n-bol];
        t[n-1-bol]=n;
    for (int i=n-2-bol;i>=0;i--) t[i]=t[i+1]-1;//Заполняем массивы значениями сокращенного факториала
    int[] b = new int[men];
        b[0]=1;
    for (int i=1;i<b.length;i++) b[i]=b[i-1]+1;
    double k =t[0]/b[0];
    for (int i=1;i<b.length;i++){          //Вычисляем К последовательно разделив и умножив
        k=k/b[i]*t[i];
        if (k>1000000000) return -1;
    }
    for (int i=b.length;i<t.length;i++) {         // где-то тут ошибка в проверке на 10^9
        if (t[i]>1000000000/k) return -1;
        k*=t[i];
        if (t[i]>1000000000/k) return -1;
    }
    long c = (long) k;
    return c;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   int t=in.nextInt();
    long[] a=new long[t];
   for (int i=0;i<t;i++){
        int n=in.nextInt();
        int m=in.nextInt();
       a[i]=Combine(n,m);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
       if (a[i]!=-1) System.out.println(a[i]);
       else System.out.println("Too big!");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: а что не так с кодом? Не могли бы вы нажать править под вопросом, добавить ожидаемое и реальное поведене программы? а то ответить на вопрос "что не так?" - очень сложно

Comment: извините, не подумал

Comment: Зря вы в задаче на комбинаторику уходите в область вещественных чисел..

Comment: Ну и, вы до сих пор не добавили ожидаемого и полученного результата - что значит "Программа выдает неправильный ответ"?

Comment: Дело в том, что я и сам не знаю. Тк закидываю задачу в тестер, а он просто выдает:"Ошибка на тесте n..". С вычислительной точки, все правильно, но я уверен, что ошибка  в том, что неправильно реализовано сравнение с 10^9